# Como repartir uma imagem em pedaços usando javascript e colocar em suas respectivas divs

Tags: javascript, html5

Gostaria de saber como é feita essa separação da imagem em divs menores dentro da própria div seguindo o exemplo desse link:

http://www.2meter3.de/jqPuzzle/demos/o1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só CSS é o suficiente

https://fiddle.jshell.net/o0g1bqzc/

O javascript até pode ser usado para pegar uma imagem e gerar o CSS. Mas no exemplo useu só o CSS

Comment: Gilsones, estou muito grato pela resposta, obrigado =)

Comment: ou a quem souber, como gerar esse css com o javascript,  independente do tamanho da imagem na div?